# How to click on button many times in the same activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `TextView` and `Button` in `RecyclerView` I put text on `Button` as number when I clicked the button I want that number increase by 1 when I try recursive `setonclicklistener` the application doesn't work 
I have two activities each of them call the same adapter
the code of adapter

```
    public class AzkaarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AzkaarAdapter.AzkaarViewHolder>  {
    ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms=new ArrayList<AzkarForm>();
    Context ctx;

    private static ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback;

    public interface ItemClickCallback {
        void onItemClick(int p);
        void onSecondaryIconClick(int p);
    }

    public void setItemClickCallback(final ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
        this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    }
    public  AzkaarAdapter (ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms,Context ctx){
        this.azkarForms=azkarForms;
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public AzkaarViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        AzkaarViewHolder azkaarViewHolder;
        if(ctx instanceof MainActivity){
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout,parent,false);
         azkaarViewHolder=new AzkaarViewHolder(view,ctx,azkarForms);
        }
        else {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_details,parent,false);
             azkaarViewHolder=new AzkaarViewHolder(view,ctx,azkarForms);
        }
        return azkaarViewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AzkaarViewHolder holder, int position) {

        AzkarForm azkarForm=azkarForms.get(position);
        if(ctx instanceof MainActivity) {
            holder.sample.setText(azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
            holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(azkarForm.getNumber()));
        }else {
            holder.sample.setText(azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
            holder.tally_count.setText(getTextNumber(azkarForm.getNumber()));

        }

    }

    public String getTextNumber(int number){
        String numberText="";
        switch (number){
            case 1:
                numberText="مرة واحدة";
                break;
            case 3:
                numberText="ثلاث مرات";
                break;
            case 4:
                numberText="أربع مرات";
                break;
            case 7:
                numberText="سبع مرات";
                break;
            case 10:
                numberText="عشر مرات";
                break;
            case 100:
                numberText="مائة مرة";
                break;
        }
        return numberText;

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return azkarForms.size();
    }

    public static  class AzkaarViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView sample, number;
        View container;
        Context ctx;
        ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms = new ArrayList<AzkarForm>();
        Button tally_count,press,next;


        public AzkaarViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx, ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms) {
            super(itemView);
            this.ctx = ctx;


            //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.azkarForms = azkarForms;
            if(this.ctx instanceof MainActivity) {
                sample = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sample);
                number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
                container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
                container.setOnClickListener(this);
            }else {
                sample = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sample);
                tally_count=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);
                press=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.press);
                press.setOnClickListener(this);
                next=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.next);
            }
            //container.setOnClickListener(this);



        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (v.getId() == R.id.container){
                itemClickCallback.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            } else {
                itemClickCallback.onSecondaryIconClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }

            /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View)sample, "qoute");

                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, p1);
            }*/


        }
    }

}
```

**First Activity**

```
  recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewcard);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter=new AzkaarAdapter(AzkaarData.getArrayListData(),this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setItemClickCallback(this);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

     @Override
    public void onItemClick(int p) {
        //int position=getAdapterPosition();
        AzkarForm azkarForm= list.get(p);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("numbers",azkarForm.getNumber());
        intent.putExtra("sample",azkarForm.getSample());
        intent.putExtra("complete",azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
        intent.putExtra("position",p);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSecondaryIconClick(int p) {

    }
```

**Second Activity**

```
recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewcard);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(DetailsActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos);
    adapter=new AzkaarAdapter(AzkaarData.getArrayListData(),this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int p) {

}

@Override
public void onSecondaryIconClick(int p) {

    AzkarForm azkarForm= list.get(p);
    press=(Button) findViewById(R.id.press);
    int currentNum=Integer.parseInt(press.getText().toString());
    int num=azkarForm.getNumber();

    if(currentNum<num){
        currentNum++;
        onSecondaryIconClick(p);
    }

    press.setText(String.valueOf(currentNum));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, first off there is no need for your `SecondaryIconClick` callback, all because you want it to do something else doesn't mean you need two of them, you can just set the same `ItemCallback` interface for both activities and then call a `switch` statement to know which widget was clicked from the layouts. It's easier for me to show you with the code you have provided, ***I haven't tested any of this code.***

From what I can see the First `Activity`, works fine (I assume this isn't causing the issues in question). Except for readability I would suggest initializing a global instance of the `Context` (`private Context context = this`) for that `activity` and then instead of `new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class)` you should have `new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class)` because sometimes `'this'` can point to the `ClickListener` rather than the `Activity`.

For the Second `Activity` the logic for the `counter` and `setText` for the `button` seems fine except you have already initialized your `Button` in the `ViewHolder`, so you don't need to initialize it again in the click listener. All you have to do is pass the view to the listener. (see my edit for the `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` code) also, I don't know why you're calling a new instance of the click event if the `currentNum < num`.

*Do you want the clicks to be automatic up until a certain number or just everytime they click up until a certain number?*

Anyway, let's solve this problem for you. I'm writing this code with the assumption you want the counter to go up everytime the user clicks `R.id.press`.

**FirstActivity**

So as I suggest above change the context reference.

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.container: 
             AzkarForm azkarForm= list.get(position);
             Intent intent=new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("numbers",azkarForm.getNumber());
             intent.putExtra("sample",azkarForm.getSample());
             intent.putExtra("complete",azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
             intent.putExtra("position", position);
             context.startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
```

**SecondActivity**

```
recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewcard);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(DetailsActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos);
    adapter=new AzkaarAdapter(AzkaarData.getArrayListData(),this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
   switch(v.getId()) {
      case R.id.press:
          AzkarForm azkarForm= list.get(position);
          int currentNum=Integer.parseInt(press.getText().toString());
          int num = azkarForm.getNumber();
              if(currentNum < num){
                 currentNum++;
              }
          v.setText(String.valueOf(currentNum));
          break;
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

Your new interface callbacks should be:

```
public interface ItemClickCallback {
        void onItemClick(View v, int position);
    }

public void setItemClickCallback(final ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
        this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    }
```

**ViewHolder**

Your new click listener should look like:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (itemClickCallback != null) {
                itemClickCallback.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View)sample, "qoute");

                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, p1);
            }*/
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you have a clean framework for your listeners and you're passing the correct `views` and calling the correct `context`, you're able to apply the logic accordingly without confusion between `callbacks`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works fine but when I return to recyclerview and click on it, it dosen't respond when I remove set of adapter in the second activity it works

Comment: Can you expand on the problem you're having then?

Comment: when I click on any item in first activity the second activity is launch but when return back to first activity to click on another item the event on click not responding , I'm trying to remove setting the listener to adapter in second activity then the click on first activity is responding

Comment: I put     adapter.setItemClickCallback(this);
in onResume() method and it works. Thanks for helping me, You make me understand the relation between activities and interface more than before

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button counter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.counter_button);
counter.setText("1");

counter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    int currNum = Integer.parseInt(counter.getText().toString());
    counter.setText("" + currNum + 1);
  }
});
```

Replace button id as per your layout.

Comment: I try this concept but I need the button click executed many times